# Check Past Orders on iTunes Online

Tags: itunes

I've purchased a few games for my iPhone, via App Store. I understand that I can check my past orders via iTunes program downloaded on my PC.

But is there anyway to check what are my past orders online, without going through iTunes the Desktop Program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way built into iOS or the App Store that will tell you what your past purchases were. However, whenever you buy something from the iTunes Store, Apple emails you a receipt of the purchase. You don't get a receipt for free items, but you should be able to keep track of your past purchases anywhere you can get access to your email.